# server vs. page level reverse proxy

Tags: nginx

A single page Meteor application needs to do reverse proxy from http to https. I found it can be done either via nginx or web page code like this:

```
if (window.location.protocol != "https:")
  window.location.href = "https:" + window.location.href.substring(window.location.protocol.length);
```

What are the disadvantages of just putting the above 2 lines of code vs. go through learning and configuring nginx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One disadvantage is that if your client is not a web browser (e.g., a crawler or a screen-scraper), it will never switch over to HTTPS.

It will also increase traffic on your web server, which will have to serve the JavaScript code to everyone connecting via HTTP, then serve it again when they redirect to HTTPS.